# C# Add image to pictureboxes with List

Tags: c#, image, winforms, list, picturebox

First of all, sorry for my english.

I'm making a program that has about 60 pictureboxes. (pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, till pictureBox60)

And I have a list with 60 strings. (urls to different images)

I want for pictureBox1 to load the list[0], pictureBox2 to load the list[1], etc..

But i realized i can't make the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Bans.Count; i++)
{
    this.pictureBox + i = this.Bans[i]; //Can't be done.. 
}
```

Is there a solution that does not require me to manually set all 60 boxes?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is WinForms, you can use `ControlCollection.Find` to get controls by name - assuming each of your `pictureboxN` controls has a matching `.Name` property value.

e.g.

```
pictureBox23.Name = "pictureBox23";
```

like so:

```
for( int i = 0; i < this.Bans.Count; i++ ) {

    String pictureBoxName = "pictureBox" + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Control[] matchingPictureBoxes = this.Controls.Find( pictureBoxName, searchAllChildren: true );
    if( matchingPictureBoxes.Length == 1 ) {
        PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)controls[0];
        pictureBox.Image = this.Bans[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works like charm